# Why is this CAML Query returning all items regardless of the <Where> element

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

I'm trying to retrieve a list of items where a specific field matches a specific value.
Here's what my CAML query:

```
                    Query query = new SPQuery();
                    SPQuery query2014 = new SPQuery();
                    query2014.Query = @"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Text'>" + 2014 + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

                    SPListItemCollection Items2014 = list.GetItems(query2014);
                    if (Items2014.Count == 0 )
                    {
                        SPListItem Item2 = list.Items.Add();
                        Item2["Year"] = "2014";
                        Item2.Update();
                    }
```

Comment: You are missing an <And> after your where.

Comment: Why Add <And>??

Comment: There should be no `<And>` just remove the `<Query>` attributes and you will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like you are using server object model using c#.

I have faced issues using CAML queries. My queries were not able to pull data, But after removing `<Query></Query>` tag I was able to solve the problem.

So based on my past experience I can propose you following improvements and try the below code.

```
Query query = new SPQuery();
                SPQuery query2014 = new SPQuery();
                query2014.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Text'>" + 2014 + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                SPListItemCollection Items2014 = list.GetItems(query2014);
                if (Items2014.Count == 0 )
                {
                    SPListItem Item2 = list.Items.Add();
                    Item2["Year"] = "2014";
                    Item2.Update();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with your SPQuery and if you pass an invalid one. When SharePoint parse the XML and detected it is invalid it passes instead of your default query a CAML Query that looks like this.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>-1</Value>
        </Neq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

So this query will return all the items.

Answer (score 0):

**Check if a ListItem exists using CAML**

```
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Year' /><Value Type='Text'>2014</Value></Eq></Where>";

if (list.GetItems(spQuery).Count == 0)
{
    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
    item["Year"] = "2014";
    item.Update();
}
```

**Check if a ListItem exists using LINQ**

```
if(list.Items.OfType<SPListItem>().Any(i => i["Year"] == "2014"))
{
    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();
    item["Year"] = "2014";
    item.Update();
}
```